# How to ask a running monerod instance for mining hashrate when restricted-rpc is enabled?

Tags: monerod, mining, hashrate

I'm running `monerod` as service, mining with 3 threads. How can I get the hashrate info?

`monerod status` fails to connect:

```
$ monerod status                                                                            
Error: Couldn't connect to daemon: 127.0.0.1:18081
Height: 1480810/1480810 (100.0%) on mainnet, mining info unavailable, net hash 644.80 MH/s, v6, up to date, 9(out)+36(in) connections, uptime 1d 1h 47m 55s
$ netstat -nap | grep 18081                                                                 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:18081           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
```

The port is open (`telnet 127.0.0.1 18081` connects properly).

**edit:** I noticed the `restricted-rpc` option blocks mining info from being accessed. The node is public and I need to keep that option. So, the question is how can I check hashrate in such setup?

Answer (score 1):

You probably started monerod with --restricted-rpc. This will deny access to the mining information, as it is private (ie, none of any third party's business).

You can now start a daemon with two RPC ports, one with restricted RPC (presumably exposed to the internet) and one not. See this in `monerod --help`:

`--rpc-bind-port arg (=18081)          Port for RPC server
  --rpc-restricted-bind-port arg        Port for restricted RPC server`

Another way is to ask the JSON RPC directly:

`curl -v -X POST http://127.0.0.1:18081/mining_status -d '{}' -H 'Content-Type: application/json'`

You then get the hash rate in the `speed` field.

Comment: I'm using v0.11.1.0-release and it seems to lack the --rpc-restricted-bind-port option. I see it's present in the last source from master. Can I still get that info from official release?

Comment: It was added since that release. You could find the patch and cherry-pick it onto the release branch if you wanted.